# Game of Life using React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, conways-game-of-life

Currently I am working on [Building Game of Life in FCC](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/build-the-game-of-life) and I thought this would be a great project to test my knowledge on React-Redux.

Since I am a new to Redux, I am having difficulty to understand what is a dumb component vs a smart component in this project.

In my view, this is how I see:
[image]

NOTE: when I say "Smart Component" vs "Dumb Component" I simply mean that to be a "Smart Component" it is a container, or something that ties with the app's state, where as a "Dumb Component" simply means it's job is to simply render whatever it's being fed on.

If my assumption is correct, then I am having hard time to setup the app state correctly on the cells.

Here's what I've written so far:

**component/board.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Cell from '../containers/cell'

export default class Board extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {height: 18, width: 40}
    this.test = this.test.bind(this)
  }
  test(){
    console.log(this.state)
  }
  render(){
    let rows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.height; i++){
      let rowID = `row${i}`
      let bin = []
      for (var idx = 0; idx < this.state.width; idx++){
        let cellID = `cell${i}-${idx}`
        bin.push(<Cell key={cellID} id={cellID}/>)
      }
      rows.push(<tr key={i} id={rowID}>{bin}</tr>)
    }
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col s12 board"></div>
            <table id="simple-board">
               <tbody>
                 {rows}
               </tbody>
             </table>
          </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**container/cell.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// import from '../actions/index';
// import { connect } from 'react-redux';
// import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';


export default class Cell extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      color: 'dead'
    };
    this.test = this.test.bind(this);
  }

  test(){
    this.state.color === 'dead' ? this.setState({color:'alive'}) : this.setState({color:'dead'})
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <td
        className={this.state.color}
        key={this.props.cellID}
        id={this.props.cellID}
        onClick={this.test}>
      </td>
    )
  }
}

// function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
//   return bindActionCreators({}, dispatch)
// }

// export default connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)()
```

I'm not sure how I can approach at this point. At first I thought about having to wrap all the cells in an array and that would be the app's state, but I am not sure how to go on about that.

Any response will be greatly appreciated

Comment: In `cell.js`, Isn't `key={this.props.cellID}` supposed to be `key={this.props.key}` and `id={this.props.cellID}` be `id={this.props.id}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you make your hierarchy like this. I'm going to represent the component hierarchy as a JSON-like syntax just so that you can understand:

```
App (smart) {
  dispatchProps: {
    ...gameControlActions, // gets passed into GameControls
    onCellClick, // gets passed down to Board, and then to each Cell
  }
  stateProps: {
    cells: [{
      id: #
      status: 'dead', // or 'alive'
    }], // gets passed down to Board, to render cells
    ...generationData, // gets passed down to Generation
  }
}
  // Children of App
  GameControls (dumb) // start, clear, randomize
  Board (dumb)
    Cells (dumb)
  Generation (dumb)
```

When you render the Cells, you would render them like this:

```
<Cell key={cellID} id={cellID} status={status} onClick={this.props.onCellClick} />
```

Inside the `Cell` component the `render` function would look like this and you can now get rid of `state`:

```
render(){
  return (
    <td
      className={this.props.status}
      id={this.props.id}
      onClick={this.props.onClick.bind(null, this.props.id)}>
    </td>
  )
}
```

Your `onCellClick` action would simply look like this:

```
function onCellClick(cellId) {
  return {
    type: 'CELL_CLICK',
    payload: cellId,
  };
}
```

You would then process that action in your reducer by toggling the `status` of that cell in your cells array (remember to return a new copy of `cells`). Also, and if necessary, you might need to make your `Cell` component extend `PureComponent`, in order to speed up the reconciliation process or to implement `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Let me know if this doesn't make sense, or if you have questions (I think you will).

Comment: I agree with everything but one thing: there is a chance a cell component being that trivial may not gain anything from sCU (and in fact become even slower).

Comment: Yeah, don't want to prematurely optimize. One should really measure the performance before doing that. Updated my answer.

Comment: thanks all for the reply! I will look into this tomorrow morning.